# JSTL FoEach Checking containsIgnoreCase set in RequestScope

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a List of Cities set in requestScope by servlet .

This is my code

I have added the required Taglibs

Could you please tell me why the containsIgnoreCase is not working

```
public class City {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int population;

    // getters and setters 
}

// 

<c:forEach items="${requestScope.cityList}" var="city">
            <tr>

        <c:if test = "${fn:containsIgnoreCase(${city.name}, 'NewYork')}">
         <p>Add a Color Here for NewYork <p>
      </c:if>

            <c:if test = "${fn:containsIgnoreCase(${city.name}, 'Houston')}">
         <p>Add a Color Here Houston <p>
      </c:if>


                <td><c:out value="${city.id}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${city.name}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${city.population}"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `${fn:containsIgnoreCase(city.name, 'NewYork')}`. You're already inside a JSP EL expression, so using `${}` again inside that expresion is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The containsIgnoreCase is not valid because you try to open an expression (`${city.name}`) inside another expression (`${fn:containsIgnoreCase()}`).

You should simplify your code to:

```
<c:if test = "${fn:containsIgnoreCase(city.name, 'Houston')}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest EL expressions.

`${city.name}` will evaluate to null when inside another EL expression. That's why it doesn't work.

You are allowed to concatenate them though:

`${foo}${bar}`

What you can do in your case is set a local variable within the forEach block like so:

```
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.cityList}" var="city">
 <c:set var="cityVar" value="${city.name}" />
                <tr>

            <c:if test = "${fn:containsIgnoreCase(cityVar, 'NewYork')}">
             <p>Add a Color Here for NewYork <p>
          </c:if>

                <c:if test = "${fn:containsIgnoreCase(cityVar, 'Houston')}">
             <p>Add a Color Here Houston <p>
          </c:if>


                    <td><c:out value="${city.id}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${city.name}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${city.population}"></c:out></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

Hope that helps